# Laravel: Where to Add booted and booting Callbacks?

Tags: php, events, laravel, callback

The main Laravel application object has two methods, `booting` and `booted`.  These methods allow you to configure callbacks.  The application object will call these callbacks before and after it boots.

Where, as a Laravel application developer, can I hook into these events?  Looking at the framework it seems like

```
bootstrap/start.php
```

is the obvious place — but if I put code here it'll be zapped in the next update.  There's also

```
start/global.php
statt/{$env}.php
```

but these files are actually required in by a `booted` callback, which means the `booting` callback point would be unavailable.

Is there an intended place for me to hook into these events as a Laravel application developer?  Or are `booting` and `booted` there for the core framework developers?  Or has I made an incorrect assumption that I'm not even aware of? Laravel 4.2.6, but if there's context from additional versions I'd love to hear about it.

New to Laravel, not new to programming.  Not asking for a specific task (yet), just getting a feel for what best practices/intended use is and is not.

Comment: Why will start.php be zapped? As long as it's not within the vendors folder any laravel updates won't change your files. Start.php is generated when you create a base project, but should not be changed with further updates.

Comment: @Scopey Ah, one of those assumptions I didn't know I'd made. I was thinking along the lines of "It was a file I didn't put there so clearly it's owned by the system" .  Do you know where/when/how start.php is generated?

Comment: Did you use `composer create-project`?

Comment: The `create-project` option copies the repo and runs some command line actions after the clone is complete. In this case it run artisan commands to setup the application for the first time. `composer update`s from now on will only update the vendor folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a formal answer, there's no defined place for this behaviour. But a note against your comments about `start.php`, this file will not be "zapped" when you update laravel.

As long as a file is not within the vendors folder, any laravel updates won't change your files. `start.php` is generated when you create a base project, but should not be changed with further updates.

`composer create-project` is responsible for creating your base "skeleton" application, and any `composer update` that you do will just modify files in the vendor folder. Just remember, do not modify files in the vendor folder and you will be fine!